# Docker Compose in Gitlab CI does not work

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following part of GitLab CI, with which I have tried to run [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools):

```
docker-compose-playgroound:
    stage: docker-compose-playgroound
    image: docker:18
    services:
        - docker:18-dind
    tags:
        - docker-main
    variables:
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    script:
        - docker compose -f .gitlab/docker-compose-autotests.yml up
```

However as output I get:

```
docker compose -f .gitlab/docker-compose-autotests.yml up
```

Output:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f
See 'docker --help'.
Usage:    docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
A self-sufficient runtime for containers
Options: ...
```

Here is also configuration of my GitLab runner:

```
18 [[runners]]
19   name = "xxxx"
20   url = "https://gitlab.xxxxx/"
21   token = "xxx"
22   executor = "docker"
23   [runners.custom_build_dir]
24   [runners.cache]
25     [runners.cache.s3]
26     [runners.cache.gcs]
27     [runners.cache.azure]
28   [runners.docker]
29     tls_verify = true
30     image = "docker:18"
31     privileged = false
32     disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
33     oom_kill_disable = false
34     disable_cache = false
35     volumes = ["/home/gitlab-runner/cache"]
36     cache_dir = "/home/gitlab-runner/cache"
37     shm_size = 0
```

How can I fix it? Or how can I use Docker Compose in a valid way in GitLab CI?

Comment: Try using a modern version of the docker image for `image:` and `services:` -- like version 24 instead of version 18 which is quite old.

Comment: As a followup to this... `docker compose` isn't even a valid command in docker version 18, so that's likely at least one problem you have there. The command `docker compose` was introduced around 2020, while docker version 18 predates this by a couple years.

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 18 of Docker, whose [last update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/18.09/) (in 2019) predates the release of the V2 compose (`docker compose`) command in 2020. You need to use a newer version of Docker for your `image:` and `services:` section in order to use `docker compose`. Alternatively, you can use V1 compose (`docker-compose`) however it no longer receives support/updates as of last year.